# Is there a connection between Riemann sum and Dual space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let the functional on $C[a,b]$ be given by

$\int_a^b \psi(t)\sin t dt$

where $\psi(t)$ is continuous on $a[a,b]$

Since the integral can be described by Riemann sum:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)$

then a question that comes to mind is:

Is there a connection between the truncated Riemann sum and the dual space of $C[a,b]$?

More specifically, are the individual parts of the Riemann sum,
$\sum_{i=2}^{3}f(t_2)(x_{3}-x_2)$

$\in C^*[a,b]$?

Comment: $\sum_{i=2}^{3}f(t_2)(x_{3}-x_2)$ sounds awkward (it is equal to $2f(t_2)(x_{3}-x_2)$).

Comment: For any $t$, the ("evaluation", or "Dirac") functional $\delta_t:f\mapsto f(t)$ belongs to the dual space. Hence so does your linear combination $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i).$

Comment: Thanks Anne, your confirmation was vital for understanding the concept of elements in dual space.

Comment: @AnneBauval does the same principle apply if we rather than writing "$\sin x$" in that functional and use the series of sin, then since it is a sum, the truncated terms of the sum of the sine series are then also  $\in C^*[a,b]$?

Comment: I answered your question about Riemann sums but I don't see the relationship with the integral at the begining of your post, involving the $\sin$ function. To answer your last comment: the $\sin$ function and the partial sums of its power series are elements of $C[a,b]$, not of its dual.

Comment: That would be another question. In Formin and Kolmogorov, they say a functional can be written in the form $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(e_k)f_k(x)$. Using my functional at the top, let sine be a series, then its sum components such as $-x^3/3!$ are they also $\in C[a,b]^*$?

Comment: Great, thanks for that Anne! Bonne journée!

Comment: I cannot find your formula in Fomin and Kolmogorov. Anyway, it would need some context, and if you want to apply it to your situation, you should first rewrite it $F(f)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty F(e_k)F_k(f).$ Here, $\sin$ and its partial sums are *functions* $f$, not *functionals* $F,F_k.$

Comment: It is on page 185, at the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141347/discussion-between-luthier415hz-and-anne-bauval).

Comment: I only see a finite sum.